# What does this marking mean? The star and swirl with 4312 over it

Tags: piano, notation

[image]

What does this notation in the treble clef mean?

Answer (score 15):

This is the symbol for a "turn" (the swirl, that is). Here's how I would play it:

[image: notes to play the turn]

The turn is positioned over the second half of the note; the "star" is not a star, but a double-sharp symbol, meaning that the "below" note of the turn (G) is a G-double-sharp.

(It usually helps if you name the piece: this is no. 4 in E minor from Chopin's preludes.)

Comment: And to add to this: 4312 is the intended fingering for the swirl.  (The swirl itself, as a conventional ornament, is not written out in full, but the fingering is added by the editors, who have chosen to write it out as it is rather non-obvious.)

Comment: The actual name for this symbol is called a “gruppetto”.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes:  I don't think "actual name" is appropriate; "gruppetto" is the Italian term, but in English, it is normally referred to as a "turn". See for example Gardner Read, Music Notation, p. 246